# How to configure Log4j for Spring on JBoss

Tags: spring, jboss, log4j

I am trying to deploy spring mvc + tiles demo project on my JBoss 5.1.0GA server. I run into this issue with Log4J:

```
    02:35:49,443 ERROR [StandardContext] Error listenerStart
02:35:49,443 ERROR [StandardContext] Context [/travel] startup failed due to previous errors
02:35:49,443 INFO  [[/travel]] Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[Loaded org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener from jar:file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/travel.war!/WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar]
02:35:49,444 ERROR [[/travel]] Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.log4j.LogManager
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:249)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:131)
        at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:645)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.<clinit>(ContextCleanupListener.java:43)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3949)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:4615)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4437)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:310)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:142)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:461)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
        at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
        at $Proxy38.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
        at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
        at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62)
```

And here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Enables use of HTTP methods PUT and DELETE -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>httpMethodFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>travel</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/META-INF/spring/travel/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>travel</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I am thinking that cause of this might be double log4j.jar on classpath but how do I check?

Comment: I think , first, you can add the argument -verbose:class to your JBoss to check out which org.apache.log4j.LogManager is actually loaded if it is suspicious that mutiple Log4J jars reside in the classpath. It will print out all the class loading information.

Comment: OK, found two:
[Loaded org.apache.log4j.LogManager from file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/lib/log4j-boot.jar]
[Loaded org.apache.log4j.LogManager from jar:file:/opt/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/travel.war!/WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar]

In my pom.xml file in Maven build I have 'runtime' scope for log4j. Should I remove log4j from war or remove from JBoss? What's the approach here?

Comment: Change its scope to provided, at least in my company it's a recommendation. However, it might need some more configurtion to let Jboss's logging make peace with your app's. See here http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-log/jboss-log4j-configuration and or Google some other similar articles, they should be helpful. @ZeC